# Firefox Extension, Window related sidebar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm writing an extension for Firefox, and I need the UI of this extension to be on a sidebar, I followed some mozilla tutorials, but sidebars are not related to just one window.

I need a sidebar like UI, that will save navigation data from the same window, and need it to be related to just that window, something like firebug.

What I did so far is just creating a menu, and an item, I need that a click on this item will toggle my sidebar.

I took a look at firebug source, I didn't find any overlay of sidebar in its XUL, the scripts are complicated for me, so i didn't know how they can add their UI to the window.

Any ideas, or sources I can read about this ?

Answer (score 1):

When talking about a Sidebar one needs to be careful about terminology. The specific term that Mozilla uses within Firefox for "[Sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Sidebar)" refers to a content box that is on the side of the UI. The Sidebar, if open, is a constant part of the UI which is shown independent of the tab selected.  Only one is provided for which can be chosen to be on the left or the right. It is routinely used for content that does not change from tab to tab (e.g. Bookmarks, or History).

The UI that is used for the Firefox devtools (and placement was adopted for use by FireBug) is a sub-panel within the current tab. It is shown only within the tab in which it was invoked. It is implemented within an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/iframe). It can also be opened as a separate window.

When you have a known working example, one way to figure out how this type of thing is implemented in the DOM (the entire browser window is a DOM) is to install the [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) [DOM Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Inspector) and use it to investigate what the contents of the DOM looks like. You probably also want, the [Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) add-on which is a very useful addition to the DOM Inspector (shift-right-click opens the DOM Inspector to the element clicked). You might also find [Stacked Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stacked-inspector/?src=api) helpful.

Another way to figure out how it is being done is to look at the source code. For the devtools the interface is actually created in the function `SH_create` within `resource:///modules/devtools/framework/toolbox-hosts.js`

When placed at the bottom location, the UI is placed as a child of the [`<notificationbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/notificationbox) which exists for each tab. You can find the `<notificationbox>` for a tab by using the `gBrowser.getNotificationBox( browserForTab )` method.  The elements inserted are a `<splitter>` and an `<iframe>`.  When placed in the other locations within the browser tab those two elements are inserted at locations in the Browser DOM either as children of the `<notificationbox>`, or as children of its child `<hbox>` that has `class="browserSidebarContainer"`.

As an example, the following functions will, depending on the [location] parameter, create a panel on the left, right, top, or bottom of the current tab or as a separate window. The default is that the panel is composed of an `<iframe>` separated from the browser content by a `<splitter>`.  The createInterfacePanel() function is more generic and will accept any element or DOM object as the second parameter which is inserted into the DOM at the appropriate place based on [location] and separated by a  form the content. Such Object is expect to be either a [Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) or [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

```
/**
 *   Creates an <iframe> based panel within the current tab,
 *   or opens a window, for use as an user interface box.
 *   If it is not a window, it is associated with the current
 *   browser tab.
 * @param location 
 *        Placement of the panel [right|left|top|bottom|window]
 *        The default location is "right".
 * @param size
 *        Width if on left or right. Height if top or bottom.
 *        Both width and height if location="window" unless
 *        features is a string. 
 *        Default is 400.
 * @param id
 *        The ID to assign to the iframe. Default is
 *        "makyen-interface-panel"
 *        The <splitter> will be assigned the
 *        ID = id + "-splitter"
 * @param chromeUrl
 *        This is the chrome://  URL to use for the contents
 *        of the iframe or the window.
 *        the default is:
 *        "chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul"
 * @param features
 *        The features string for the window. See:
 *        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open
 * returns [splitterEl, iframeEl]
 *        The elements for the <splitter> and <iframe>
 *
 * Copyright 2014 by Makyen.
 * Released under the MPL 2.0. http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
 **/
function createInterfacePanelIframe(location,size,id,chromeUrl,features) {
    //defaults
    size = ( (typeof size !== "number") || size<1) ? 400 : size; 
    id = typeof id !== "string" ? "makyen-interface-panel" : id;
    chromeUrl = typeof chromeUrl !== "string"
        ? "chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul"
        : chromeUrl;

    //Create some common variables if they do not exist.
    //  This should work from any Firefox context.
    //  Depending on the context in which the function is being run,
    //  this could be simplified.
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        //If there is no window defined, get the most recent.
        var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                           .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    }
    if (typeof document === "undefined") {
        //If there is no document defined, get it
        var document = window.content.document;
    }
    if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
        //If there is no gBrowser defined, get it
        var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
    }

    //Get the current tab & notification box (container for tab UI).
    let tab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
    let browserForTab = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab( tab );
    let notificationBox = gBrowser.getNotificationBox( browserForTab );
    let ownerDocument = gBrowser.ownerDocument;

    //Create the <iframe> use
    //ownerDocument for the XUL namespace.
    let iframeEl = ownerDocument.createElement("iframe");
    iframeEl.id = id;
    iframeEl.setAttribute("src",chromeUrl);
    iframeEl.setAttribute("height", size.toString());
    iframeEl.setAttribute("width", size.toString());

    //Call createInterfacePanel, pass the size if it is to be a window.
    let splitterEl;
    if(location == "window" ) {
        splitterEl = createInterfacePanel(location, size, size
                                        ,id + "-splitter", chromeUrl, features);
        return [splitterEl, null];
    } else {
        splitterEl = createInterfacePanel(location, iframeEl, iframeEl
                                        ,id + "-splitter", chromeUrl, features);
    }
    return [splitterEl, iframeEl];
}

/**
 * Creates a panel within the current tab, or opens a window, for use as a
 *   user interface box. If not a window, it is associated with the current
 *   browser tab.
 * @param location 
 *        Placement of the panel [right|left|top|bottom|window]
 *        The default location is "right".
 * @param objectEl
 *        The element of an XUL object that will be inserted into
 *        the DOM such that it is within the current tab.
 *        Some examples of possible objects are <iframe>,
 *        <browser>, <box>, <hbox>, <vbox>, etc.
 *        If the location="window" and features is not a string
 *        and this is a number then it is used as the width of the
 *        window.
 *        If features is a string, it is assumed the width is
 *        set in that, or elsewhere (e.g. in the XUL).
 * @param sizeEl
 *        The element that contains attributes of "width" and 
 *        "height". If location=="left"|"right" then the 
 *        "height" attribute is removed prior to the objectEl
 *        being inserted into the DOM.
 *        A spearate reference for the size element in case the
 *        objectEl is a documentFragment containing multiple elements.
 *        However, normal usage is for objectEl === sizeEl when
 *        location != "window".
 *        When location == "window" and features is not a string,
 *        and sizeEl is a number then it is used as the height
 *        of the window.
 *        If features is a string, it is assumed the height is
 *        set in that, or elsewhere (e.g. in the XUL).
 * @param id
 *        The ID to assign to the <splitter>. The default is:
 *        "makyen-interface-panel-splitter".
 * @param chromeUrl
 *        This is the chrome://  URL to use for the contents
 *        of the window.
 *        the default is:
 *        "chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul"
 * @param features
 *        The features string for the window. See:
 *        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open
 * returns
 *        if location != "window":
 *           splitterEl, The element for the <splitter>.
 *        if location == "window":
 *           The windowObjectReference returned by window.open().
 *
 * Copyright 2014 by Makyen.
 * Released under the MPL 2.0. http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
 **/
function createInterfacePanel(location,objectEl,sizeEl,id,chromeUrl,features) {
    //Set location default:
    location = typeof location !== "string" ? "right" : location;
    if(location == "window") {
        if(typeof features !== "string") {
            let width = "";
            let height = "";
            if(typeof objectEl == "number") {
                width = "width=" + objectEl.toString() + ",";
            }
            if(typeof sizeEl == "number") {
                height = "height=" + sizeEl.toString() + ",";
            }
            features = width + height
                       + "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,personalbar=no"
                       + ",status=no,chrome=yes,resizable,centerscreen";
        }
    }
    id = typeof id !== "string" ? "makyen-interface-panel-splitter" : id;
    chromeUrl = typeof chromeUrl !== "string"
        ? "chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox.xul"
        : chromeUrl;

    //Create some common variables if they do not exist.
    //  This should work from any Firefox context.
    //  Depending on the context in which the function is being run,
    //  this could be simplified.
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        //If there is no window defined, get the most recent.
        var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                           .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    }
    if (typeof document === "undefined") {
        //If there is no document defined, get it
        var document = window.content.document;
    }
    if (typeof gBrowser === "undefined") {
        //If there is no gBrowser defined, get it
        var gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
    }

    //Get the current tab & notification box (container for tab UI).
    let tab = gBrowser.selectedTab;
    let browserForTab = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab( tab );
    let notificationBox = gBrowser.getNotificationBox( browserForTab );
    let ownerDocument = gBrowser.ownerDocument;


    //Create a Document Fragment.
    //If doing multiple DOM additions, we should be in the habit
    //  of doing things in a way which causes the least number of reflows.
    //  We know that we are going to add more than one thing, so use a
    //  document fragment.
    let docFrag = ownerDocument.createDocumentFragment();

    //ownerDocument must be used here in order to have the XUL namespace
    //  or the splitter causes problems.
    //  createElementNS() does not work here.
    let splitterEl = ownerDocument.createElement("splitter");
    splitterEl.id =  id ;

    //Look for the child element with class="browserSidebarContainer".
    //It is the element in procimity to which the <splitter>
    //and objectEl will be placed.
    let theChild = notificationBox.firstChild;
    while (!theChild.hasAttribute("class")
        || !theChild.getAttribute("class").contains("browserSidebarContainer")
    ) {
        theChild = theChild.nextSibling;
        if(!theChild) {
            //We failed to find the correct node.
            //This implies that the structure Firefox
            //  uses has changed significantly and it should 
            //  be assumed that the extension is no longer compatible.
            return null;
        }
    }

    let toReturn = null;
    switch(location) {
        case "window"    :
            return window.open(chromeUrl,"_blank",features);
            break;
        case "top"    :
            if(sizeEl) {
                sizeEl.removeAttribute("width");
            }
            docFrag.appendChild(objectEl);
            docFrag.appendChild(splitterEl);
            //Inserting the document fragment results in the same
            //  DOM structure as if you Inserted each child of the
            //  fragment separately. (i.e. the document fragment
            //  is just a temporary container).
            //Insert the interface prior to theChild.
            toReturn = notificationBox.insertBefore(docFrag,theChild);
            break;
        case "bottom" :
            if(sizeEl) {
                sizeEl.removeAttribute("width");
            }
            docFrag.appendChild(splitterEl);
            docFrag.appendChild(objectEl);
            //Insert the interface just after theChild.
            toReturn = notificationBox.insertBefore(docFrag,theChild.nextSibling);
            break;
        case "left"   :
            if(sizeEl) {
                sizeEl.removeAttribute("height");
            }
            docFrag.appendChild(objectEl);
            //Splitter is second in this orientaiton.
            docFrag.appendChild(splitterEl);
            //Insert the interface as the first child of theChild.
            toReturn = theChild.insertBefore(docFrag,theChild.firstChild);
            break;
        case "right"  :
        default       :
            //Right orientaiton, the default.
            if(sizeEl) {
                sizeEl.removeAttribute("height");
            }
            docFrag.appendChild(splitterEl);
            docFrag.appendChild(objectEl);
            //Insert the interface as the last child of theChild.
            toReturn = theChild.appendChild(docFrag);
            break;
    }
    return splitterEl;
}
```

### Update:

The code in this answer was significantly enhanced for my answer to "[Firefox SDK Add-on with a sidebar on both the right and left at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959921/3773011)". You are probably much better off using the code contained in that answer rather than the code found here.

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation, I have used the firefox add-on sdk, it offers a nicer interface for creating different chrome objects.